# How to skip first element in each line of matrix?

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, cycle

I have next matrix:

```
1 4 2 1 3 5
2 3 1 2 4 5
3 4 5 3 2 1
4 5 1 3 4 2
5 3 2 4 5 1
```

and I am writing it from text file to 2d array starting from second line in file in this cycle:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(@"input_5_5.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1250)).Skip(1))
            {
                    foreach (var col in line.Trim().Split(' '))
                    {
                        result[i, j] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
                        j++;
                    }
                    i++;
            }
```

I need to skip first element in each line of matrix and write to array `result` from second element in every line because first element in row of matrix is only number of row.

Comment: You skip the first line using a Linq method. Apply the same *within* each line to skip the first element. You will also want to fix the usage of `j` and probably adjust the array sizes accordingly.

Comment: Where do you initialize `i`? (for loops would be better here instead of foreach)

Comment: What is the reason you are using `int[,]` instead of `int[][]`?

Comment: @flindeberg because all the lines of the array are of the same length?

Comment: @Sayse that would indeed be a reason, but I was asking OP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead use (if you need to know which line/col).
Col is initialized with 1 since you don't need first column.

```
string[] fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"input_5_5.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));
for(int line = 0; line < fileLines.Length; line++)
{
    string[] splittedLines = fileLines[line].Trim().Split(' ');
    for(int col = 1; col < splittedLines.Length; col++)
    {
        // do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

Comment: This will most likely result in an invalid result (if not an exception) as `j` is never reset per line.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise to simply skip `foreach` and use a regular `for` loop.
After trimming and splitting the line by space(s), simply skip the 1st element by initializing the index to 1 instead of 0.

`var cols = line.Trim().Split(' '); //use string split option to remove empty entries for robustness`

`for (int j = 1; j < cols.Length; j++) //note the j is initialized with 1, instead of 0`

Note - All this assumes that either the data is known to be well formed, or you do appropriate bounds and error checks etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many variations on how to do this, but you want to start j at 1 instead of 0. that was you're missing element 0, which I believe if what you're after, so:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(@"input_5_5.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1250)))
{
    int j = 1;
    foreach (var col in line.Trim().Split(' '))
    {
        result[i, j] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My exercise for this question, though some Linqs can still be shortcircuited, this may be more clear:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LinqArraySkipFirstColumnAndLine()
    {
        var inputString = @"SkipThisLine
                            1 4 2 1 3 5
                            2 3 1 2 4 5 
                            3 4 5 3 2 1
                            4 5 1 3 4 2
                            5 3 2 4 5 1";

        char[] lineSeparator = new char[] { '\n' };
        char[] itemSeparator = new char[] { ' ' };

        var lines = inputString.Split(lineSeparator).Skip(1);
        Assert.AreEqual(5, lines.Count(), "Expect 5 rows");

        List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>();

        lines.ToList().ForEach(line => {
            int dummy = 0;
            var items = line.Trim()
                            .Split(itemSeparator,
                                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .Skip(1);
            Assert.AreEqual(5, items.Count(), "Expect 5 items each row");

            var row = items.Where(c => int.TryParse(c, out dummy))
                           .Select(w => dummy).ToList();
            matrix.Add(row);
        });

        var elements = from row in matrix
                       from cell in row
                       select cell;
        Assert.AreEqual(25, elements.Count(), "Expect 25 elements after flattening matrix");
    }
```